# Remote crontrol from Android mobile (over the internet) working in Wayland

Tags: remote-desktop, vnc, wayland, remote

For some time I've been using VNC Server on my Ubuntu laptop and VNC Viewer (client) to connect from my Android phone over the internet and control the laptop. It works very, very well and it is reliable. But, as Wayland is being pushed, my VNC Server does not work on Wayland and I have to find some alternative. Meanwhile, I cannot use Wayland because of this.

Does anyone have some solution to this? To make sure, I make a summary: Android phone to Linux box (Ubuntu in my case), on Wayland.

Thank you very much.